# How to get 3 functions to run synchronously in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous

First question ever.  Learned from StackOverflow for years. Just cant figure this out.

I've tried to wrap my head around callbacks, promises and async/await - I'm just not seeing it.  Can someone *please* help?

I just cant get it to do: **1**, then **2**, then **3**.

1. Download a PDF
2. Convert PDF to JPGs
3. Delete PDF

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const { exec } = require("child_process");
const targetUrl = 'http://domain/fileProxy.ashx?token=';
const previewpath = 'previews/';

var token = '66a7e572-e2fb-4fb4-87a9-6e19d675357f';
var orderNo = '121212';

function getPdf() {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(orderNo+ ".pdf");
    http.get(targetUrl+token, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        console.log('downloaded');
    });
}
    
function makeJpgs() {
    exec("magick -density 150 -quality 100% " + orderNo + ".pdf " + previewpath + orderNo + ".jpg");
    console.log('converted');
}

function deletePdf() {
    fs.unlink(orderNo+ ".pdf", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
    console.log('deleted');
}

getPdf();
makeJpgs();
deletePdf();
```

Comment: FYI, what you're asking for is how to **sequence** three asynchronous operations to run serially one after the other.  You're not able to run them synchronously as they are asynchronous operations so your title is using the wrong term when it asks for "synchronously".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way of doing it is to continue execution in the callback. The **minimal** modification needed to get your code working:

```
function getPdf() {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(orderNo+ ".pdf");
    http.get(targetUrl+token, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        console.log('downloaded');
        makeJpgs(); // CONTINUED HERE!
    });
}
    
function makeJpgs() {
    // 
    exec("magick -density 150 -quality 100% " + orderNo + ".pdf " + previewpath + orderNo + ".jpg", function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        else {
            deletePdf(); // CONTINUED HERE!
        }
    });
    console.log('converted');
}

function deletePdf() {
    fs.unlink(orderNo+ ".pdf", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err); // You can't really throw asynchronously
        }
        else {
            // Deletion process completes here.
            console.log('deleted');
        }
    });
    // console.log('deleted'); // Note: The file haven't even started being deleted here
}

getPdf();
```

With Promises you can make your code a bit more readable:

```
const util = require('util');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const child_process = require("child_process");
const targetUrl = 'http://domain/fileProxy.ashx?token=';
const previewpath = 'previews/';

var token = '66a7e572-e2fb-4fb4-87a9-6e19d675357f';
var orderNo = '121212';

const exec = util.promisify(child_process.exec);
const unlink = util.promisify(fs.unlink);
const get = function (url) {
    return new Promise(function(ok,fail){
        http.get(targetUrl+token, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            ok();
        })
        .on('error',fail);
    });
}

function getPdf() {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(orderNo+ ".pdf");
    return get(targetUrl+token);
}
    
function makeJpgs() {
    return exec("magick -density 150 -quality 100% " + orderNo + ".pdf " + previewpath + orderNo + ".jpg");
}

function deletePdf() {
    return unlink(orderNo+ ".pdf", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    });
}

getPdf().then(function(){
    console.log('downloaded');
    return makeJpgs();
}).then(function(){
    console.log('converted');
    deletePdf();
}).then(fuction(){
    console.log('deleted');
});
```

Now that your functions return promises you can use async/await:

```
async function main () {
    await getPdf();
    console.log('downloaded');
    await makeJpgs();
    console.log('converted');
    await deletePdf();
    console.log('deleted');
}

main().then('done');
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now I have an example I can actually understand and apply.  Thank you again sir!

Comment: @AndrewJ I wasn't finished. Check out the updated answer

Comment: fyi `fs` provides promises `const { unlink } = require('fs').promises` and it doesn't need the callback, although i assume that's ignored.